# Opc-UA communication protocol , How does the client understand about available server nodes?

Tags: sockets, opc, opc-ua, node-opcua

As am starting out with opc ua , i just wanted to know what happens under the hood of the communication layer of opc ua.

Lets take an example of a very simple server implementation that has 3 nodes in the address space. These nodes present data that can be written and read by an opc-UA client.

From reading a part of the code that comes with open62541, i've learnt that the communication happen via TCP. Meaning the server initiates a socket that a client can connect to and enable the client to 
perform various operations on the nodes.

My question is, how does the client know about available server nodes ? I know it browses through the address space but where exactly does it browse to find available nodes ?
 what exposure mechanism does opc-UA use to present available nodes to the client ?. Does the server write available information & nodes on a some xml file or anywhere else and hence when a clients connects, it tries to read the contents of the file to understand the addressSpace structure ?

Sample server implementation for open62541

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <open62541.h>
#include <signal.h>

static void
addVariable(UA_Server *server) {
    /* Define the attribute of the myInteger variable node */
    UA_VariableAttributes attr = UA_VariableAttributes_default;
    UA_Int32 myInteger = 43;
    UA_Variant_setScalar(&attr.value, &myInteger, &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_INT32]);
    attr.description = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "the answer");
    attr.displayName = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "the answer");
    attr.dataType = UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_INT32].typeId;
    attr.accessLevel = UA_ACCESSLEVELMASK_READ | UA_ACCESSLEVELMASK_WRITE;

    /* Add the variable node to the information model */
    UA_NodeId myIntegerNodeId = UA_NODEID_STRING(1, "the.answer");
    UA_QualifiedName myIntegerName = UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(1, "the answer");
    UA_NodeId parentNodeId = UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_OBJECTSFOLDER);
    UA_NodeId parentReferenceNodeId = UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_ORGANIZES);
    UA_Server_addVariableNode(server, myIntegerNodeId, parentNodeId,
        parentReferenceNodeId, myIntegerName,
        UA_NODEID_NULL, attr, NULL, NULL);
}

static void
addThirdVariable(UA_Server *server) {
    /* Define the attribute of the myInteger variable node */
    UA_VariableAttributes attr = UA_VariableAttributes_default;
    UA_String myInteger = UA_STRING("My name is variable 3"); // variable name
    UA_Variant_setScalar(&attr.value, &myInteger, &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_STRING]);
    attr.description = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "the answer");
    attr.displayName = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "the answer");
    attr.dataType = UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_STRING].typeId;
    attr.accessLevel = UA_ACCESSLEVELMASK_READ | UA_ACCESSLEVELMASK_WRITE;

    /* Add the variable node to the information model */
    UA_NodeId myIntegerNodeId = UA_NODEID_STRING(1, "third.variable");
    UA_QualifiedName myIntegerName = UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(1, "third varaible");
    UA_NodeId parentNodeId = UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_OBJECTSFOLDER);
    UA_NodeId parentReferenceNodeId = UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_ORGANIZES);
    UA_Server_addVariableNode(server, myIntegerNodeId, parentNodeId,
        parentReferenceNodeId, myIntegerName,
        UA_NODEID_NULL, attr, NULL, NULL);
}

void addSecondVariable(UA_Server * server) {
    //variable attributes
    UA_VariableAttributes attr = UA_VariableAttributes_default;
    UA_String machine_name = UA_STRING("My name is a machine"); // variable name
    UA_Variant_setScalar(&attr.value, &machine_name, &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_STRING]);

    attr.description = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "machine name");
    attr.displayName = UA_LOCALIZEDTEXT("en-US", "machine name");
    attr.dataType = UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_STRING].typeId;
    //setting access level not important

    //add the variable to the information model
    UA_NodeId myStringNodeID = UA_NODEID_STRING(1, "the.machine");
    UA_QualifiedName myStringName = UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(1, "the machine");
    UA_NodeId parentNodeId = UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_OBJECTSFOLDER);
    UA_NodeId parentReferenceNodeId = UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_ORGANIZES);

    UA_Server_addVariableNode(server, myStringNodeID, parentNodeId,
        parentReferenceNodeId, myStringName,
        UA_NODEID_NULL, attr, NULL, NULL);



}

UA_Boolean running = true;
static void stopHandler(int sign) {
    UA_LOG_INFO(UA_Log_Stdout, UA_LOGCATEGORY_SERVER, "received ctrl-c");
    running = false;
}

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGINT, stopHandler);
    signal(SIGTERM, stopHandler);

    UA_ServerConfig *config = UA_ServerConfig_new_default();
    UA_Server *server = UA_Server_new(config);
    addVariable(server);
    addSecondVariable(server);
    addThirdVariable(server);
    UA_StatusCode retval = UA_Server_run(server, &running);


    UA_Server_delete(server);
    UA_ServerConfig_delete(config);
    return (int)retval;
}
```

Comment: The OPC UA Client shall use the Services FindServers and GetEndpoints. I will recommend you first to get some information about OPC UA. There is a list of books for OPC UA here : https://opcfoundation.org/resources/books/

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can discover Nodes.

First and foremost, you should be aware that the AddressSpace is not a tree, but a graph. The nodes of the graph are the OPC UA `Node`s, and the edges of the graph are OPC UA `Reference`s.

The name of a `Node` is a `NodeId` which is a qualified name. The name is either an integer (`i=`), a string (`s=`), or an opaque object (`o=`). The qualifier designates a `Namespace` in the server's namespace table.

About namespaces, there are two reserved namespace indices:

- `0`, which designates the OPC UA namespace
- `1`, which designated the server itself (IMHO, you should have one different per server)

The OPC UA Foundation is master of the OPC UA namespace, and defines a whole bunch of standard nodes in the `0` namespace. In particular the nodes `Server`, `Objects` and `Types` are defined in the `0` namespace, with well-known integer names. I won't talk about the `Attribute`s of a `Node`, but given the concepts of `Node`, `Reference`, `Namespace` and `Attribute`, the OPC UA Standard pulls itself by the bootstraps. The `0` namespace defines the base structure of the nodes of a server, and all defined nodes have well-known `NodeId`s. I said "bootstrap", because in paricular under the `Server` node is located the `NamespaceTable` which associates the namespace indices to the corresponding namespace URNs. (including the standardized indices `0` and `1`) The elements of the table can be `Read` just like any other node.

To begin answering your question, in short, the most direct way of accessing a particular node within a server is to know its `NodeId`.

Now, how can you know what nodes are present on a server, if you don't have a list? Well, the operation is known as `Browsing`, and there are two flavours about it: following `Reference`s, or teleporting through `BrowsePath`s.

About following references, remember I said that the `AddressSpace` is a graph. Well, a `Node` points to other `Node`s through `Reference`s. Given a particular `NodeId` (e.g. a well known `NodeId`, or the root, which also has a well-known `NodeId` in the namespace `0`), you can query the references of the `Node` which will designate other `Node`s, and follow the trail that is of interest to you  from `Node`to `Node`, until you find what you are looking for. This implies lots of exchanges between the client and the server, and honestly is seldomly worth the hassle.

About teleporting through `BrowsePath`s, there is a service called `TranslateBrowsePath` implemented by the server where given a start `NodeId`and a browse path, the server gives you the list of nodes that match the query. (i.e. reachable from the designated start `Node` through a path of `Reference`s matching the browse path) The browse path language is very rich, and you can make rather complex queries with it.

Answer (score 0):

The client can discover nodes in the server using the Browse service.

There are some pre-defined Nodes present in every server that the client can start the browse from. Typically that would be either the Root folder or the Objects folder.

Comment: Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 0):

The nodes are identified by a structure of type **NodeId**.

If you program an OPC UA client you would have to add the functionality of navigate through the node's tree so the user can choose the **NodeId(s)** he wants to read or write their attributes, among them the value.

To navigate through the tree you need to use the **Browse** service, to read the attributes you need the **Read** service. 
Browse returns the children of a given node.

But to use these services you first have to create a session, for which you have to call first GetEndpoints, OpenSecureChannel, CreateSession,  ActivateSession .... services

Comment: Thanks @Tonteria24 , i had to capture the packets to figure out the client to server call sequence as in GetEndpoints, openSecureChannel ..... browse/read .

Comment: I do not think that sniffing packages you get enough far ... the thing is a bit/quite complicated, but it is well documented. You can download the specs for free from the OPC foundation. About services, parts 4 and 6 would be the most important.